# What is the difference between running an application as a service and as an administrator on Windows OS?

Tags: privileges, smb, network-share, windows-security, local-system-account

I am working on some application that needs to access the **windows network shares**. I have some functionality broken in my app if I run it as a system service. The same logic works fine when I run my app as an Administrator. This made me curious to know the difference between running a process as a System service vs Administrator, especially dealing with network shares. Any information or relevant links is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One reason might be because when you run it as **Service** it runs under your current credentials but when you run it as **Administrator** you are running the application with an unrestricted token.

This post might interest you although I don't know how relevant it will be to your program: [How to add a service SID to a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197908/how-to-add-a-service-sid-to-a-service).